# Which items are Missable or Limited in Quantity?

Tags: final-fantasy-the-4-heroes-of-light

In Final Fantasy: The 4 Heroes of Light one of the things availble to do is getting all items

Which items have one of the following properties:

- Have a limited quantity or are unique.
- Stop being sold in the stores after a certain point.
- Are available multiple times, but only from limited sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are items that you can miss in the game.

Items obtained from people during the adventure:

1. Inherited Ring from Kuore in Horne
2. Apollo's Talisman from Apollo in Liberte
3. Mythril Hammer from the Weapon Shop vendor in Invidia

Items available for sale only before defeating Rolan in Rolan's Soul:

1. Elementalist Robe in Invidia or Spelvia
2. Ranger Outfit in Invidia or Spelvia
3. Traveler's Garb in Horne or Guera
4. Black Ring in Spelvia
5. Silence Cape in Arbor
6. Flame Dagger in Liberte or Invidia

Items unique to bosses:

1. Earth Sword - Drop from first version of Sand Devil
2. Lightbringer - Steal from either version of Rolan or Lucifer
3. Claustrum - Steal from the first version of Mammon
4. Darkbringer - Steal from either version of Satan
5. Adventurer's Garb - Drop/Steal from Adventurer

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961297-final-fantasy-the-4-heroes-of-light/56487909)

Comment: What about Krinjh's Sword?  Is there a way to get it other than stripping him before he leaves the party?

Comment: Also, the King's Shortsword is not missable, but is of limited quantity. You only get one, so if you sell it you're out of luck. It's one of the best swords in the game.